# How do I turn off the h2 console in a java project in the IntelliJ Idea development environment?

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, spring-security, h2

I want to put my program in a Docker container. However, my project has an h2 database that opens its console at the start of the project in the browser. As a result, an error appears when starting the container:
**Failed to start a browser to open the URL http://172.17.0.2:8082?key=9cfa612432aa32f89b955f102b129e4b8123dcec3f9841e74c6bd5e319f3a3a5: Browser detection failed, and java property

'h2.browser' and environment variable BROWSER are not set to a browser executable.**

As a result, it was decided to go the easy way and disable the h2 console, since I still don't use it yet. Following the advice of chat-gpt-3, I tried to disable it using the **application.properties** file :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.DriverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
spring.h2.console.path=/myh2console
```

I created a jar artifact and launched it using the command: **java -jar out/artifacts/KameleoonTestTask_jar/KameleoonTestTask.jar**

But it did not bring the desired result. As soon as I launch the artifact, a new tab opens in the browser with the h2 database window and prompts me to enter a name and password, and the h2 database console icon appears at the bottom of the tray.

Then following his other advice I tried disabling the console by denying the console access to the browser using SpringSecurity:

```
package project.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.Enable Web Security;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(Http Security http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizerequest()
        .antMatchers("/h2-console/*").denyAll()
        .and().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}
```

The console keeps popping up.

It is also worth noting that the console does not appear during the normal launch of the application in Idea. It appears only when I run the artifact with the above command. I run the artifact manually to check how the program will behave inside the docker container.

If anyone knows how to disable this console, please help.

Comment: *However, my project has an h2 database that opens its console at the start of the project in the browser.* How do you open a browser in your Docker container? What kind of docker container do you use? Anyway, Spring Boot doesn't open a browser by default. You have to do it by yourself (manual or coding).

Comment: *Browser detection failed, and java property
'h2.browser' and environment variable BROWSER are not set to a browser executable.* This error is clear, your app cannot open a browser. So you have to change your code, to not open any browser.

Comment: How do you open a browser in your Docker container?
The H2 database tries to open it.
_
What kind of docker container do you use?
I am creating a Docker Container from this image.

FROM openjdk:11
MAINTAINER Sergey Zavyalov
COPY out/artifacts/KameleoonTestTask_jar/KameleoonTestTask.jar /app/KameleoonTestTask.jar
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/KameleoonTestTask.jar"]

Comment: What kind of docker container do you use?
part2
_
Then I create an image
docker build -t sergzv/kameleoon:v0.0.1 .
_
Then I create a container
docker run --rm --name testtask sergzv/kameleoon:v0.0.1

Comment: What kind of docker container do you use? Anyway, Spring Boot doesn't open a browser by default. You have to do it by yourself.
Yes, I read about it. And this is the strangest thing. Therefore, I am now trying to create a new project and see if there will be this error in it. I repeat, with a simple launch of the project, there is no console. It only occurs when I create artifacts and run it in the terminal via the java -jar command out/artifacts/KameleoonTestTask_jar/KameleoonTestTask.jar . Is it possible that this is the case?

Comment: This error is clear, your app cannot open a browser. So you have to change your code, to not open any browser. 
Yes, this is the way I decided to go. Actually, that was my question. How to disable the console, which should already be disabled by default so that it does not launch the browser when the application starts. In addition, I read that the console is needed only for tests and in ready-made applications it should be disabled.

Comment: The only way I know how to get the web console to pop up is if I explicitly start the H2 DB server - for example, using `java -cp h2-2.1.214.jar org.h2.tools.Server -baseDir .` (and there are other equivalent ways, also). When I do that, I see a `Web Console server running at ...` message. On the other hand, if I only have a web app running with a JDBC connection, I never see the console (including when running on the command line).

Comment: You are using an in-memory H2 instance - so is it safe to assume you do not have any code in your Spring Boot app doing anything like this: `Server server = Server.createTcpServer(args).start();`? Or any other place where there is an explicit command to start the H2 in server mode?

Comment: Everything is right. I don't explicitly call the h2 database start anywhere. Except in application.properties (the settings of which I described in the main question), when connecting dependencies in pom.xml I don't call it anywhere. I don't know if it's possible to give a link to the full project here and whether anyone will dig into it, but just in case here https://github.com/SERGZV/KameleoonTestTask .

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. What have I done for this:

1. I installed the latest 30-day trial version of Idea Ultimate
2. In pom.xml I removed all the plugins that were there and added this one:

   <plugin>
   org.springframework.boot
   spring-boot-maven-plugin
   </plugin>
3. This time I did not build the JAR artifact using Idea (File > Project Structure > + JAR from modules with dependencies).
   Now I produced it with Maven (Go to "Toolbar" from the right with the name Maven > "name of your project" > Lifecycle > package)
4. Now the artifact is in the target folder and when I run it using "java -jar..." the login window to the h2database console no longer opens in the browser
5. Of course, in order for Docker container to use a new artifact, I changed the path in the Makefile and re-created the image and the container based on the new JAR file.

Now, during the launch of the Docker file or the jar artifact itself, the H2 console window does not pop up in the browser.